# PFUser currentUser doesn't save/retrieve custom attribute correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-login

I'm using Parse with Facebook login. The first screen in my app is the login screen with a custom Facebook login button. When the button is clicked, it executes this:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:@[@"email"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login error" message:error.description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        return;
    }

    if (user.isNew) {
        user[@"usernameIsSet"] = @NO;
        [user saveEventually:nil];
    }

    if ([user[@"usernameIsSet"] boolValue] == NO) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushRegister" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

Basically, I'm attaching a property called `usernameIsSet` to the `PFUser` because I want to know if the user has explicitly supplied a username, not the one that Parse automatically assigns. That way, the text time the app opens, the root view controller (a tab bar controller) checks if the user already has a username, and if not, display the Register screen as a modal. This is the tab bar controller's `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        BOOL usernameIsSet = [currentUser[@"usernameIsSet"] boolValue];
        if (!usernameIsSet) {
            RegisterViewController *registerScreen = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterViewController"];
            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:registerScreen];
            [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {

        }
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"presentLogin" sender:self];
    }
}
```

When the Register screen appears and the user types in a username and the Done button is clicked, the following method is triggered:

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    user[@"username"] = self.textField.text;
    user[@"usernameIsSet"] = @YES;
    [user saveEventually:nil];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What I don't understand is this:

The first time the app is installed and runs, all my code above works as expected. Login is shown, Facebook permissions are granted, then the Register screen appears just to ask the user to assign a username. The username is assigned, `user[@"usernameIsSet"]` is set to `@YES`, the modal is dismissed, the tab bar controller's `viewDidAppear` is called, and `currentUser[@"usernameIsSet"]` is still `YES`.

**BUT**, when I terminate the run from Xcode and run it again, the tab bar controller's `viewDidAppear` gets executed and `currentUser[@"usernameIsSet"]` is already `NO`.

What's the problem here? I look at the Data Browser in Parse and the `usernameIsSet` column contains true, together with the user-assigned username.

Comment: How do you know the save eventually has completed before you kill the app?

Comment: Does `[PFUser currentUser]` return a value when the app launches? Is there actually a logged in user at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be:

> `saveEventually` does not write through any caches at this time,
>   including the `currentUser`, if the app has been restarted. You'll need
>   to regularly call `fetch` to keep it up-to-date.

From: https://parse.com/questions/when-you-modify-a-pfuser-does-it-write-through-the-authenticated-user-cache

Comment: How does Fetch help here? If the data hasn't been written through the cache, and you kill the app, the data is gone? I'm facing this exact problem, not sure how to keep the currentUser additional fields valid :(